# How do i find the decryption key for a encrypted text file

Tags: encryption, decryption, cheat-engine, game-hacking

So context i have a game and a encrypted save file. My thoughts were how to find the decryption key in reverse engineering my game .I watched tuts but i think this topic isnt much detailed so i need advice guys.

Comment: Welcome to RE.SE! No idea how many games exist out there, but you _need_ to add more details as this question is very broad as of now. Pretend for a minute that you have only the information you give in your "question" and then reflect on this.

Answer (score 1):

*I voted to close this question because it is, unfortunately, too broad to properly answer.*

One has to gain some knowledge and experience in the reverse engineering world before one can tackle some of the real-world scenarios. you may want to start with learning assembly and doing a few crackmes, which are designed to improve one's reverse engineering skills.

Then, you could use this Stack Exchange site to ask *specific* questions about difficulties and challenges encountered. Alternatively, you can edit this question or post a new one with what you've done so far and what prevents you advancing forward.

Comment: "this" (i.e., [reverseengineering.se]) is not a [so] site, it's a [se] site.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of the subtle difference. I often treat the two as synonyms... feel free to correct if this bothers you.